# Testing whether an integer is the sum of two squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, sums-of-squares

Is there a fast (probabilistic or deterministic) algorithm for determining whether an integer $n$ is a sum of two squares?

By "fast" here I mean polynomial time (i.e. time $O((\log n)^{O(1)})$). Note that I am interested only in whether the integer can be represented in such a way, not in *how* it is represented.

Since a fast algorithm is required, it will not do to use factorization.

It would be odd if this turned out to be harder than detecting primality, since prime numbers are rarer.

(This is a question that came up in a talk I just gave.)

Comment: I wouldn't expect detecting representable numbers to be substantially easier than computing such a representation. There is a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm for finding these representations by Rabin and Shallit (http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160390713), but it only works for primes, which is the case you are not interested in (detecting whether a prime can be represented is trivial).

Comment: @J.C. Ottem: "Polynomial time" in this context generally means "polynomial in the number of bits needed to represent the input", i.e. polynomial in $log(n)$. Harald makes this completely clear in the question.

Comment: "It would be odd if this turned out to be harder than detecting primality, since prime numbers are rarer." This intuition seems completely false to me. I can test whether $n$ is a power of $3$ is $O((\log n)^2)$, and that's a very rare condition!

Comment: @David: Yes, I realized this just after posting, besides it wasn't meant as a serious comment... :)

Comment: @Emil: If a prime p is 1 mod 4 then a representation p=a^2+b^2 can be found in deterministic polynomial time. First use Schoof's algorithm (Math. Comp. 44 (1985), 483-494) to find a solution of x^2 = -1 mod p in polynomial time, then use the Euclidean algorithm in Gaussian integers to find a+bi=gcd(p,x+i) in polynomial time.

Comment: An idea that does not help : It is equivalent to ask to check if the conic $x^2+y^2 = n$ has a rational solution. But unless I factor $n$, I would not know at which finitely many primes $p$ I have to check locally solubility.

Comment: There is a simple method using triangular numbers that can find the representation of a number N as a sum of two squares without having to factor N but the timing is not known. The details can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972771/is-this-the-general-solution-of-finding-the-two-original-squares-that-add-up-to

Answer (score 13):

This problem is equivalent to detecting whether there is some prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$ dividing the number which is raised to an odd power.  In the worst case, where the number is a large semiprime equivalent to 1 mod 4, this is almost surely as hard as FACTORIZATION.  If it was easy, then it would give away the second-lowest bit in both prime factors of such numbers; if we had enough information of this type we could recover the factors via Coppersmith's algorithm.

Practically, check the number mod 4 (once you remove trailing 0s) and see if it's 3, then trial divide by small primes.

Comment: Please explain - how would you use Coppersmith's algorithm? What information would you be assuming, precisely?

Comment: ?? You would CRT all the known residues together so that for one of the primes dividing n, p = r mod m.  Then use Coppersmith to find numbers in that residue class which have a nontrivial gcd with n, recovering the factor.  Isn't that a standard use of the algorithm?  Of course you'd need a lot of information, but Coppersmith makes "a lot" a much smaller number than if the only available algorithm was testing numbers of the form r, r+m, r+2m, ... sequentially.  (Obviously, if only a *very* small amount of information is known, general-purpose factorization is faster.)

Comment: See also Tao's answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer .

Comment: @Charles How do you get second-lowest bit?

Comment: @VS. No method is known or believed to exist. Tao has a post on his blog about this.

Comment: @Charles I mean I want to know 'If it was easy, then it would give away the second-lowest bit in both prime factors of such numbers'. Also what is the blog link?

Comment: @VS. Suppose you have a semiprime that's 1 mod 4. (If it was 3 mod 4 you'd know it wasn't a sum of squares already.) If you learn that it's a sum of two squares, the prime factors are both 1 mod 4 (or equal). If you learn it's not the sum of two squares, the prime factors are both 3 mod 4. Either way you go from knowing their last bit to knowing their last 2 bits.

Answer (score 12):

There are situations where we know that a number is a sum of two squares although we do not know the factorization, and in fact know very little about the factors. [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67601/which-fibonacci-numbers-are-the-sum-of-two-squares), for example, notes that $F_{2k+1}=F_k^2+F_{k+1}^2$ (the $F_k$ are the Fibonacci numbers). On the flip side, though, while Fibonacci numbers are easier to factor than most, they are not trivial (I think Blair Kelly maintains [a list of factors](http://mersennus.net/fibonacci/)).

To be specific, $F_{1049}$ is a sum of two squares, but has not yet been factored.

Comment: Ditto the various $2^{2^n}+1.$

Answer (score 8):

The question is equivalent to testing whether -1 is a square modulo n. This corresponds to  the quadratic residuosity problem which is supposedly computationally hard:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem

Comment: But is testing whether -1 is a square as hard as testing whether an arbitrary residue (with Jacobi symbol 1) is a square? Testing whether an arbitrary residue is a square is the supposedly hard quadratic residuosity problem.

Comment: To expand on Peter’s comment, the quadratic residuosity problem is supposed to be hard when $n$ is a Blum integer, in which case we know a priori that $-1$ is not a square. 

Comment: Why "quadratic residuosity problem is supposed to be hard when n is a Blum integer"? It is formulated for a generic composite number. A Blum integer would be a particular case of the problem.

Comment: Can you explain your equivalence? It is not directly equivalent as, for example, 45 is a sum of two squares but -1 is not a square modulo 45.

Comment: @ndkrempel: Strictly speaking, equivalence here is with being the sum of two *coprime* squares. For non-coprime squares, we can try to cancel all possible square factors of $n$ and then test if it becomes the sum of coprime squares. In particular, for $n=45$, we have that -1 is a square modulo $45/3^2=5$.

Comment: But "cancel all possible square factors" is not known to be polynomial time, so you have not demonstrated the equivalence.

Comment: Well, at least for Blum integers mentioned above, there are no square factors, and no cancelling is required.