# Number of divisors of an integer of form 4n+1 and 4n+3

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose $n$ is a large odd integer. Let $D_1(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$ of the form $4k+1$ and let $D_3(n)$ be the number of divisors of the form $4k+3$. I would like to compute $(D_1(n),D_3(n))$.

As Joe Silverman points out, the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two squares of integers is $4(D_1(n)-D_3(n))$. For example, $D_1(225)=6$ and $D_3(225)=3$, so there are $4(6-3)=12$ lattice points on the circle of radius $\sqrt {225}$ centered at the origin including $(0,15)$ and $(-9,-12)$.

> Is there a faster way to find $(D_1(n),D_3(n))$ than factoring $n$?

---

Original:

Hi, one way to do so is to list all the divisors of the integer and check each if it is of the form $4n+1$ or $4n+3$. 
Is there any faster method to it, especially for large $n$?

Comment: Often the answer to this kind of question is 'no, it is not much easier than factorin' see for example here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer . This is of course not exactly what you are asking for, but perhaps sufficiently related to be useful.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close. Am I missing something? 

Comment: Douglas: I have not voted to close, but I find it a bit difficult to tell exactly what the asker is asking.

Comment: I agree that it could be written to be slightly clearer. I do not understand the votes to close as "too localized;" did people misread the question? This appears far from trivial. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57981/testing-whether-an-integer-is-the-sum-of-two-squares/57987#57987 

Comment: I do not see a connection between the list of divisors and the number of representations as a sum of two squares. The question on meta "if we have an oracle telling the number of divisors of two kinds, can we factor faster" is interesting but did not appear in the new edition of the question. Still I am not against reopening it since somebody thinks it is a non-trivial question.  

Comment: The question on meta is an approach to showing that the answer is "no." It is not equivalent, since it is possible that determining $(D_1(n),D_3(n))$ takes as long as factoring, but that the information doesn't help much in factoring $n$. If you feel this whole question is trivial, please elaborate, perhaps as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not quite what you're asking, but an interesting theorem of Legendre's says that the number of ways of writing an integer $N$ as a sum of two squares is $4D_1(N)-4D_3(N)$, where $D_1(N)$ is the number of positive divisors of $N$ that are congruent to 1 modulo 4 and $D_3(N)$ is the number of positive divisors of $N$ that are congruent to 3 modulo 4. There are undoubtedly also results proved via analytic methods that describe the distribution of $D_1(N)$ and $D_3(N)$. But I'd have to agree with the other posters that computing $D_1(N)$ and $D_3(N)$ for a specific $N$ sounds about as hard as factoring $N$. Indeed, if $N=pq\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, computing $D_1(N)$ is equivalent to computing the first bit in the factors of $N$, which seems hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , i too found the same solution in one of the books .

Answer (score 3):

A faster way would involve looking at the prime factorization of the integer.
Let n be pq, where q contains all the 1 mod 4 prime factors of n, and q contains all the 3 mod 4 prime factors.  Then the number of factors of n which are 3 mod 4 is just the number of factors of q times the number of 3 mod 4 factors of p, which is close to half the number of factors of p.  I'll let you finish the details, including the case that n is even.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.16

Comment: Thanks, but i was thinking if there exists any method not involving factorisation..

Comment: How are you going to list all the divisors without factorizing?  A complete list of divisors + AKS = prime factorization, so I don't think you can avoid this.

Comment: I don't need a list of all the divisors, just a list of all the prime divisors (with multiplicity).  That is tantamount to factoring the number, but is not the same as computing the list of all divisors.  I suggest a method that does not need the list of all the divisors.  (Also, I need to change a q to a p).  There may be a method to compute quickly the parity of the number of 4k+3 divisors, but the answer is still going to be 0 or about half the number of divisors of the given number n, assuming n is odd.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.16

Comment: Actually, there is a way for odd n which does not involve full factorization.  First, consult an oracle which (correctly) gives you the number of factors of n.  Second, consult another oracle which (correctly) tells you if at least one of the factors is of the form 4k+3.  Then the number of factors of the form 4k+3 will be 0 or floor(d/2), where d is the number of divisors of n, and where you need the second oracle to determine which. For even n, keep dividing by 2 first, and record the number of such divisions. Gerhard "Ask Others Directions to Delphi" Paseman, 2011.03.16

Comment: Factorization is hard, and I do not view it as significantly easier than writing out a list of all divisors. You say consult two oracles. I don't grant you those oracles as building blocks. Is it easier to get that information than factorizing $n$? As "unknown" pointed out, some types of information are expected to be about as hard as factorization.

Comment: I am answering the original question as best as I can, Douglas.  If the poster wants divisors without factoring, I can only think of puttiing the work of factoring off on someone else.  Whom else?  I don't know, and indicated as much in my signature.  Gerhard "Knows Way To San Jose" Paseman, 2011.03.17

Comment: The original question appears nontrivial. It does not say you are required to list the divisors, it says that is an unsatisfactory method. The difficulty is not the very easy step of going from the prime factorization to the counts. If you could prove that there is no way to get the counts without being able to obtain a factorization, that would be interesting.

Comment: Unfortuately, my "best" attempt was pretty poor.  While the number of factors of the form 4k+3 can be computed (and may/may not be equivalent to factorizing the number), it is not automatically floor(d/2) for d the number of divisors of n, nor is 0 always the answer.  One needs to know quite a bit more to determine the precise number of factors, especially the number of factors f such that f is 4k+1 but also that any factor of f also is 1 mod 4.  Gerhard "Shot From Hip And Missed" Paseman, 2011.03.21 