# What are the consequences of a polynomial time algorithm for finding out if a given number is expressible as the sum of two squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

This question is based on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57981/testing-whether-an-integer-is-the-sum-of-two-squares), in which it is asked if there is a polynomial time algorithm which finds out if a given number is expressible as the sum of two squares. One of the answers pointed out that this problem is essentially as hard as [Integer Factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

The wiki article on integer factorization says the following.

> Many cryptographic protocols are based on the difficulty of factoring large composite integers or a related problem, the RSA problem. An algorithm which efficiently factors an arbitrary integer would render RSA-based public-key cryptography insecure.

This prompted me to ask if there were any similar consequences if a polynomial time algorithm for finding out if a given number is expressible as the sum of two squares is discovered?

ADDENDUM: Note that I am interested only in whether the integer can be represented in such a way, not in how it is represented.

Comment: One consequence that springs to mind is that if one had such an algorithm and was able to find multiple expressions as a sum of two squares, one could then use these expressions to determine a (partial) factorization.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: If one has $N = a^2+b^2 = c^2+d^2$ for distinct decompositions as sums of squares, then one can use these decompositions to find a factor of $N$ by taking $\gcd(ac+bd,N)$; the resulting number is a nontrivial factor.

Comment: @ARupinski: $3^2+4^2=4^2+3^2=25$ but $3*4+4*3=24$, $gcd(24,25)=1$. Something is wrong?

Comment: @Mark: truly distinct decompositions - where order doesn't matter, as well as signs.

Comment: @Dror: So the comment of ARupinksi is almost correct. One needs to choose the order of summands $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$. Also it may be that $a^2+b^2$ does not have prime divisors of the form $4k+1$, in which case $a^2+b^2$ is a square which can be also easily checked. 

Answer (score 4):

John Brillhart has a short piece in the December 2009  M.A.A. Monthly, I guess Volume 116, pages 928-931, called A Note on Euler's Factoring Problem, giving full detail on using multiple decompositions as $x^2 + n y^2 $ for factoring some odd $N.$

Note that this was a principal method for factoring difficult large integers before the advent of electronic computers.  See the Dover reprint, Albert H. Beiler, Recreations in the Theory of Numbers, especially pages 239-247, on the Lehmer factoring machine in the 1930's, which worked well except when an amateur short-wave radio operator nearby was active.

Comment: I think the Beiler book was an original Dover publication, not a reprint. 

Comment: I just assumed. Inside the Beiler book, it says "is a new work published for the first time in 1964." They gave me a copy for doing best in the 1973-1974 Nassau County interscholastic mathematics league competition, my senior year in high school. I am, you see, very old.

Comment: @will:Why wouldn't the Lehmer machine work with a radio operator around?

Comment: It appears you are a high school student. I encourage you to experiment with actual factoring, for example by getting a copy of the Brillhart article. It is a little early to be saying what you do not wish to learn about. 
$$  $$
The Lehmer machine was a bunch of gears with holes. If all the gear holes lined up, a beam of light could be detected by a photoelectric cell, which would instantly stop the machine. Evidently the radio also activated the electric eye, stopping the machine at random.