# Is there another simple formula for the sum-of-squares function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

The [sum-of-squares](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html1.) function (denoted $r_{2}(n)$) gives the number of ways in which a given number $n$ is expressible as the sum of two squares. The following is from the article on this function from Wolfram Mathworld.

> > To find the the number of representations of $n$ as the sum of two squares (ignoring order and signs), factor $n$ as
> >     $$n= 2^{a_0}p_{1}^{2a_{1}}...p_{r}^{2a_{r}}q_{1}^{b_{1}}...q_{s}^{b_{s}}$$
> >     where $p_{i}$s are primes of the form $4k+3$ and $q_{i}$s are primes of the form $4k+1$. If $n$  does not have such a representation with integer $a_{i}$ because one or more of the powers of $p_{i}$ is odd, then there are no representations. Otherwise, define
> >     $$B=\prod_{i=1}^{r}(b_{i}+1)$$
> >      Then, the required number will be $0$ if any $a_{i}$ is a half-integer,$\frac{B}{2}$ if all $a_{i}$ are integers and $B$ is even, and $\frac{1}{2}(B-(-1)^{a_0})$ if all $a_{i}$ are integers and $B$ is odd.

Now the questions I want to ask are two.

1. If I want to write an algorithm to find out the value of this function at a large integer, then using the above definition wouldn't give the best result since it is required to *factor* the integer first, and Integer Factorization is known to be computationally difficult. So, is there any other formula for this function which allows us to "put in" the value of $n$ to get the required result without having to resort to finding out the prime factorization of $n$ first?
2. If there *was* such a formula for the sum-of-squares function, would that be preferred over the above? Are there any reasons why such a formula would be more advantageous?

   Thanks in advance!

Comment: The value of r_2 is stronger than a primality test for odd sums $N$ of two coprime squares since there is essentially a unique representation if and only if $N$ is prime. Moreover, the knowledge of two representations of $N$ as a sum of two squares allows you to factor $N$. This doesn't prove anything, but perhaps suggests that you should not expect too much.

Comment: Terry Tao's heuristic here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer/10062#10062 would seem to predict that you probably can't find an efficient way to compute this.

Comment: If $N=pq$ is 1 mod 4 and the product of two (large) distinct primes, then $N$ is expressible as the sum of two squares iff $p$ and $q$ are both 1 mod 4. But figuring out whether the factors are both 1 mod 4 or both 3 mod 4 is believed to be a hard problem.

Comment: For some more comments you can take a look at this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57981/testing-whether-an-integer-is-the-sum-of-two-squares that discusses how hard it is just to determine if $r_2$ is zero or not.