# Which Fibonacci numbers are the sum of two squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Fibonacci numbers ($F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$) have the identity $$F_{2k+1}=F_k^2 + F_{k+1}^2.$$
In particular, if $n$ is odd, then $F_n$ is a sum of two squares. Are there infinitely many even $n$ for which $F_n$ is a sum of two squares?

---

### Some comments (building from my notes and also from the comments and answers below)

The set of even $n$ (nonnegative, naturally) with $F_{2n}$ the sum of two squares begins
  $$\{ 0,2,6,12,14,26,38,62,74,86,98,122,134,146,158,182,222,254,$$
  $$326,338,366,398,446,614,626,698,722,794,866,1022,1046,\ldots\},$$
using the tables at [Mersennus.net](http://mersennus.net/fibonacci/). There are five entries in this list that are not 2 mod 12: three small numbers (0, 6, 12) that can be forgiven their impertinence, but also 222 and 366 (both are 6 mod 12, and also 78 mod 144).

The list of possible indices (possible because not all of the factorizations are complete) continues
  $$\ldots, 1082,1226,1238,1418,1646,1814,2174,2246,2258,2282,2294,$$
  $$2426,2498,2558,3002,3062,3302,3494,3662,3698,3782,3902,4058,$$
  $$4106,4178,4274,4394,4478,4502,4574,4622,4682,4826,4874,4898,4934,$$
  $$4946,5102,5174,5558,5594,5702,5714,5798,6074,6326,6362,6542,6614,$$
  $$6638,6746,6794,6914,6998,7022,7154,7278,7286,7382,7394,7454,7494,$$
  $$7538,7586,7694,7754,7838,7934,8006,8054,8138,8186,8222,8258,8486,$$
  $$8522,8594,8906,9038,9074,9194,9206,9242,9326,9398,9446,9638,9662,$$
  $$9782,9806,9818,9866,9902$$

This list contains two more indices that are not 2 mod 12: 7278 (possibly giving a sum of two squares) and 7494 (definitely giving a sum of two squares). Note $366-222=12^2$ and $7494-7278=6^4$. Also, all four of 222, 366, 7278, 7494 have the form $6p$ (with $p$ a prime, of course).

---

The Fibonacci numbers are periodic modulo $m$ (for any $m>1$). Considering the sequence modulo 4, for example, it repeats 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1. Since the sum of two squares is never 3 mod 4, we learn that $F_{6n+4}$ is never the sum of two squares. Varying the modulus allows us to eliminate many other congruence classes. There are some numbers, for example $F_{78}$, that are not the sum of two squares but do not seem to be eliminatable in this manner.

---

If $n$ is negative and even, then $F_n$ is negative. This restricts the possibilities for an algebraic family (such as the one that exists for odd-indices).

---

The Lucas numbers are $L_0=2,L_1=1,L_{n}=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$. The identity $F_{2n}=F_nL_n$, coupled with the easy fact that $\gcd(F_n,L_n)$ is 1 or 2, implies that $F_{2n}$ is the sum of two squares if and only if both $F_n$ and $L_n$ are.

Comment: This question might be hard. If you really want to know the answer you could try a probabilistic model (which would prove nothing but might give you a good guess). I think probably $n=2$ mod 12 is the only case you care about (as long as $n>12$) and then you get lucky with 14,26,38 but are unlucky with 50 because there's a factor of 11. You want to try and guess the probability that a large fib number with $n=2 mod 12$ is divisible by an odd power of 11, 19, ... and then take the product and hope :-)

Comment: Small observation: since $F_{2n}=(2F_{n-1}+F_n)F_n$, and $\text{gcd}(2F_{n-1}+F_n,F_n)|2$, this implies that if $F_{2n}$ is a sum of squares then so is $F_n$, as well as $2F_{n-1}+F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$.

Comment: From Eric Naslund's erased comments, it also means that Lucas number $L_n$ is the sum of two squares. For $n \leq 91,$ this is true for $n \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ itself prime or the product of such primes. However, $L_{97} = 3299 \cdot 56678557502141579.$ 

Comment: Note, the above is after Dror's comment on $F_{2n}$ and $F_n,$ as $F_{2n} = F_n L_n.$ Note that $L_{25}$ has a factor of 11, therefore $F_{50}.$ 

Comment: Also $L_{30}$ is the sum of two squares, go figure.

Comment: L_{30} is kinda irrelevant for our purposes though, since we are only interested in $2n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ (because of divisibility by $3=F_4$ issues).

Comment: I think it was an Olympiad problem once: show that the set of $n$ such that $F_n$ has a prime divisor that is 3 mod 4 has (natural) density 1/2. None of the odd $n$ have such a divisor from your square relation of above, and then one can show that almost all (but not all) the even $n$ have such a divisor.

Comment: @Junkie: This is true, and not hard to prove. See my updated answer. It follows directly from the fact that if a prime of the form $5+6k$ divides $n$, then a prime of the form $3+4k$ divides $F_{2n}$, combined with the fact that the integers not divisible by primes of the form $5+6k$ have density $0$. 

Comment: I wanted to double-vote this question, and I find the discussion of it really interesting.

Comment: Are there congruence obstructions F_{10n} or F_{20n} to be sum of 2 squares?

Answer (score 14):

This is **not a solution,** just some thoughts which are too long for a comment. I have added proofs of Will Jagy and Junkies comments/conjectures which are fairly interesting on their own.

First, the Fibonacci numbers are a [divisibility sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence), which means that $$\gcd(F_n,F_m)=F_{\gcd(n,m)}.$$
**Added:  Proof of part of Will Jagy's Observation:**

**Claim:**  If $n\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ then $L_n$, and hence $F_{2n}$ are divisible by some prime $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

*Proof:*  Look at $L_n$ modulo $4$.  Then the sequence is $L(0)\equiv 2$, $L(1)\equiv 1$, $L(2)\equiv 3$, $L(3)\equiv 0$, $L(4)\equiv 3$, $L(5)\equiv 3$, $L(6)\equiv 2$, $L(7)\equiv 1$, and at this point it must repeat.  The cycle length is $6$, and $L(5)\equiv 3$.  This means that $L(5+6k)\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ for all $k$.  Hence $L(5+6k)$ is always divisible by a prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$.

Since $L_n |L_{kn}$ when $k$ is odd, we can conclude that if $p\equiv 5 \pmod{6}$ divides $n$, then some prime $q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ must divide $F_{2n}$.  This is because either $2|n$, and hence $3|F_{2n}$, or $n$ is odd, and $L_p|L_n$ so that $q|F_{2n}$.

**Added Proof Of Junkie's Comment:**

**Claim:** The density of even Fibonacci numbers which are not divisible by *some* prime of the form $3+4k$ is $0$.

*Proof:* This is a corollary of Will Jagy's observation.  Since the density of numbers which are not divisible by a prime of the form $5+6k$ is zero, it follows from the previous claim that the density of even Fibonacci numbers not divisible by a prime of the form $3+4k$ is $0$.

*Conjectures and other thoughts:* Recall that we can write $F_n$ as a sum of two squares if it has no prime factors of the form $3+4k$.

**Conjecture 1:**  The only Fibonacci number of the form $F_{2n}$ which is divisible by some prime of the form $3+4k$ *and* can be written as the sum of two squares is $F_{12}$.

$F_{12}$ is a very special Fibonacci number for a few reasons.  One is that it is the *only* [nontrivial square](http://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html).  If we change the condition to a sum of two *nonzero* squares, then $F_{12}$ is automatically excluded.  Also, since no other Fibonacci numbers are squares, nothing else is affected.  Hence we can rephrase conjecture 1 as:

**Conjecture 1:**  If $F_{2n}$ is divisible by some prime of the form $3+4k$ then it cannot be written as the sum of two nonzero squares.

One reason for this conjecture is that it checks out numerically in [large range,](http://mersennus.net/fibonacci/) up to $F_{1000}$.  Also, it would be nice if it was true.

Assuming this, by the divisibility property, given a prime $p=3+4k$, we need *only* care about the **first time** it appears in the Fibonacci Sequence.  There is [a theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Prime_divisors_of_Fibonacci_numbers) which states that $$F_{p-\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)}\equiv 0 \pmod{p},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) $$ where $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol.  Conjecture 1 would imply that if $2n$ is divisible by $p-\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ for any $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $F_{2n}$ is not the sum of two nonzero squares.

Previously, I said some things about what happens if the above were an "if and only if" for primes of the form $3+4k$ (it clearly isn't for $1+4k$)  Small update:  It also is just false for $3+4k$, since $3571=3+4k$, is prime and divides $F_{68}$.

**Examples:** The first few primes congruent to $3$ mod $4$ less then $100$ are $$3,7,11,19,23,31,41,47,59,67,71,79,83,87$$
and they divide respectively 
$$F_4, F_8, F_{10}, F_{18}, F_{24}, F_{30}, F_{40}, F_{48}, F_{58}, F_{68}, F_{70}, F_{78}, F_{84}, F_{88}.$$

So in particular, (assuming conjecture 1) if I want $F_{2n}$ to be a sum of two nonzero squares, $2n$ cannot be divisible by any of the above.  I.e. we cannot have any of $$2|n, \ 5|n, \ 9|n,\ 29|n,\ 39|n .$$  This idea can give us a large list of primes, none of which can divide $n$, but that is about *all* I can get it to do.

Comment: I am confused by "If it was always the first, we would have the following if and only if statement" - it could still be the case that $F_{2n}$ is divisible by a prime congruent to 3 mod 4 but in even power? (As you mention yourself earlier, the condition for being a sum of two squares is an if-condition, not an if-and-only-if.)

Comment: $F_{12}  =144$.

Comment: @Vladimir, @Emil:  There were several problems with what I had previously said. (It was just some "thoughts")  I updated things so that it makes more sense, and is not so bad.


Comment: Very nice. Evidently I wrote out a little table with $F_n$ mod 3 and mod 4, but did not do the same for $L_n.$

Comment: @Will Jagy:  There is a nice easy Corollary which Junkie mentioned in a comment:  The density of even Fibonacci numbers which are _not_ divisible by a prime of the form $3+4k$ is zero.  I updated again to include this.

Comment: The quality you describe, $\gcd(F_a,F_b)=F_{\gcd(a,b)}$ is called _strong_ divisibility; divisibility itself means only that $F_a|F_b$ when $a|b.$

Comment: I was all good, until I learned that 87 has bcome prime. Before COVID-19 it was a multiple of 3. You may want to check.

Answer (score 12):

Two short remarks related to this problem and Eric's conjectures:

**1)** In the paper

> C. Ballot and F. Luca, ‘ On the
>   equation $x^2 + dx^2 = F_n$ ’, Acta Arith.
>   127 (2007), 145–155.

the authors show that the equation $x^2+y^2=F_{2n}$ has no solution for most integers $n$.

**2)** In the problem section of the 42th volume of the [Fibonacci Quarterly](http://www.fq.math.ca/42-1.html), 2004, it is shown that the set of integers $n$ such that $F_n$ is divisible by a prime of the form $4k+3$ has asymptotic density $\frac12$.

Comment: Right. I just wanted to point out these references. The paper by Ballot and Luca does not mention any results on fibonacci that can be written as a sum of two squares, so maybe the problem is still open.

Comment: Good point, it much nicer to have on hand.

Comment: @J.C. Ottern:  +1, this is very useful.  I also misunderstood something, the first claim is implies the second but not necessarily vice versa!!  


Answer (score 5):

This is similar to Eric's observations. It is certainly true that there is periodicity in taking the Lucas numbers modulo some prime, and if 0 ever appears it does so in a predictable pattern. I have been playing with these, and have a simple conjecture: if $n$ is odd and $ p | n,$ where $p \equiv 5 \pmod 6,$ then $L_n$ is divisible by a prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ where $q$ depends only on $p,$ as in the table below. Note that the bad factors all satisfy $q \equiv 11, 19 \pmod{20},$ so there may be an easy quadratic reciprocity proof for larger $p \equiv 5 \pmod 6.$ Then it is anyone's guess whether $q^2 | L_n,$ but if not then $L_n$ is not the sum of two squares. The possible use of this is in Dror's comments above and 
$ F_{2n} = F_n L_n.$

```
  p                      q
  5                     11
 11                    199
 17                   3571
 23                    139
 29                     59
 41              370248451
 47             6643838879
 53           119218851371
 59                 336419
 71        688846502588399
 83             6202401259
 89                    179
101                   7879
107        479836483312919
```

Comment: Also, you might have used this, but I'll put the link for any others reading the comments who want to play around with numerics:  This page: http://mersennus.net/fibonacci/  has lists of the complete factorization of the first 1000 Fibonacci numbers and the first 1000 Lucas Numbers.

Comment: @Eric: $F_{12}=12^2$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @Will Jagy: I added a proof of your observation at the end of my answer.


Answer (score 5):

Very different aspect, but interesting to me at least. The odd index Fibonacci numbers are one branch in the Markov tree,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

http://oeis.org/A002559

Taking notation from the book by Cusick and Flahive, we have the Markov (or Markoff) equation
$$m^2 + m_1^2 + m_2^2 = 3 m m_1 m_2,$$
where it follows from the process that generates the tree that 
$$ \gcd(m, m_1) = \gcd (m_1, m_2) = \gcd(m_2,m) = 1.$$
Then C+H define $u$ on pages 10 and 18 as the smallest positive integer such that 
$ \pm m_1 u \equiv m_2 \pmod m.$ Then we define an integer $v$ by $mv = u^2 + 1.$

It follows from $mv = u^2 + 1$ that every Markov number is represented, and primitively, as the sum of two squares.

At some point I had a proof (well, I think I did) that the Markov discriminants $$ 9 m^2 - 4 $$ were also the sum of two squares, although sometimes not primitively because these are divisible by 4 when $m$ is even. I cannot recall the proof but it was short and elementary.

PROOF: That was fun. We have $ m^2 + m_1^2 + m_2^2 = 3 m m_1 m_2$ in positive integers. We know from
$ v m = u^2 + 1$ that $m$ is not divisible by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ simply because
any $k^2 +1$ is never divisible by such a prime, since $(-1|q)=-1.$  Now, take $\delta = \pm 1,$ and assume
$$ 3 m \equiv 2 \delta \pmod q.$$
Then  $ m^2 + m_1^2 + m_2^2 \equiv 2 \delta m_1 m_2 \pmod q,$ so then 
 $ m^2 + m_1^2 - 2 \delta m_1 m_2 +  m_2^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ finally
 $$ m^2 + (m_1 -  \delta  m_2)^2  \equiv 0 \pmod q.$$
But this is a contradiction, as $m$ is not divisible by $q.$ So, in fact
$ 3 m \neq \pm 2 \pmod q,$ then $9 m^2 - 4 \neq 0 \pmod q$ for any prime
$q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $F_{2n}=F_n L_n$ here is an observation about Lucas numbers being sum of squares, unfortunately it doesn't
 answer the question (hopefully some other identity might help).

Claim: If $L_{2n}$ is sum of two squares, $L_{10n}$ is sum of two squares too and
$L_{10n}/L_{2n}$ is expressible as sum of two squares not depending on factorization.

An identity is
$$ L_{2n}^2 - 4 = 5 F_{2n}^2 $$

which allows computing $\sqrt{-5} \pmod {L_{2n}}$ (A)

Another identity is:

$$L_{10n}=L_{2n}^5-5 L_{2n}^3 + 5 L_{2n} = (L_{2n}^4 - 5 L_{2n}^2 + 5) L_{2n} $$

Solving the quartic $= 0$ over $\mathbb{R}$ gives 3 roots all of them involving $\sqrt{+5}$,
one of them is $ -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{5} + \frac{5}{2}}$.

After squaring:
$$ \sqrt{5} \equiv 2 L_{2n}^2-5 \pmod{L_{10n}/L_{2n}} $$

Combining with (A) we have $\sqrt{-1} \pmod{L_{10n}/L_{2n}}$ which allows
efficiently expressing $L_{10n}/L_{2n}$ as a sum of two squares without factoring.

Probably this is just an identity I didn't know.

sage code for computing the root

```
def LU2(n):
    """
    lucas number
    """
    pr.<Z>=ZZ[]
    K.<v>=NumberField(Z**2-5,'a')
    gr=(1+v)/2
    return ZZ (gr**n + (-gr)**(-n))

def root1(n):
    """
    square root of -1 mod L_{10n}/L_{2n}
    """
    L=LU2(10*n)
    F=LU2(2*n)
    N=L/F #L_{10n}/L_{2n}
    assert F^5-5*F^3+5*F == L
    K=IntegerModRing(N)
    sp5=((2*K(F)^2-5) )
    sm5=(K(2)/fibonacci(10*n))
    assert sp5**2==5
    assert sm5**2== -5
    rootm1=sp5/sm5
    assert rootm1**2 == -1
    return N,rootm1
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the conjecture that $6$ is the only even number such that  $F_{2n}$ is the sum of two squares then $2$ cannot divide $n$.
Then we also have $F_{2n}=F_n*L_n$ and so if $F_{2n}$ is the sum of
two squares $F_n$ is the sum of two squares since n is odd so $F_{2n}$ is the sum of two squares if $L_n$ is the sum of two squares. Also if $n$ is odd and $F_{2n}$ is the sum of two squares then $L_n$ is the sum of two squares.
  So if we assume the question is equivalent to the following
are there an infinite number of odd $n$ such that $L_n$ is the sum of two squares.