# counting irreducible factors

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, factorization

In [How hard is it to compute the number of prime factors of a given integer?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer) a question was asked on computing number of prime factors of an integer.

Suppose we have a polynomial $f(X)\in \Bbb Z[X]$ with leading coefficient $1$ and the constant term $1$, there is a polynomial time algorithm in terms of degree and size of coefficients to factor $f(X)=\prod_if_i(X)$ where each $f_i(X)$ is in $\Bbb Z[X]$.

However if I just want to count the number of irreducible factors of $f(X)$, is there a way to do this in polynomial time without factoring the polynomial?

Probably an algorithm to the question: "Given $F(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, find maximum $k$ such that $F(x)=f_1(x)^{a_1}\dots f_k(x)^{a_k}$ where $f_i(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ has $deg(f_i(x))\geq 1$ and $i\neq j\implies f_i(x)\neq f_j(x)$ with each $a_i > 0$?" is close to the question here.

Atleast can we say $k>1$ without factoring? Or would this also split the polynomial?

Comment: I don’t think there is any coherent way how to define that an algorithm does not factor the polynomial behind the scenes.

Comment: "Given $F(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, find max $k$ such that $F(x)=f_1(x)^{a_1}\dots f_k(x)^{a_k}$ where $f_i(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ has $deg(f_i(x))\geq 1$ and $i\neq j\implies f_i(x)\neq f_j(x)$ with each $a_i > 0$"?