# Computing the Moebius function $\mu$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory

Is it known whether computing $\mu(n)$ for a given integer $n$ is as hard as factorization?

Comment: Wild guess: we don't know. However, realistically (I believe Terry Tao has talked about it somewhere, will try to find it later), whatever method to compute $\mu$ we will find is likely generalize to larger number fields. Gathering such information for carefully chosen number fields will give us information about factorization of $n$ in $\mathbb N$, possibly even leading us to a full factorization. So although we might not know how to reduce factorization to finding $\mu$, a known method to find $\mu$ might lead to a factorization method.

Comment: [What I was talking about in the previous comment](http://mathoverflow.net/a/10062/30186).