# Two queries on irreducible factors without factoring - comparing integers and dense polynomials

Tags: computational-number-theory

Assume the polynomials here are dense.

In [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3820/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-given-integer) it was asked the difficulty of counting prime factors of an integer.

We know for the cases of primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and any polynomial in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ counting irreducible factors is easy since for primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ we have deterministic LLL algorithm and for any polynomial in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ we have randomized algorithms.

$1$ My first question is whether it would be possible to have an algorithm to count number of irreducible factors for either the case of primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ or the case of any polynomial in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ in at least randomized polynomial time or even in randomized subexponential time without factoring?

$2$ Given that we know how to test primality without factoring my second question is whether it would be possible to test for irreducibility without factoring polynomials?

Query $2$ is affirmative if we are in $\Bbb F_q[x]$ but unclear for primitive polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

---

What is know about these in sparse polynomial case?

Comment: What does it mean for a polynomial to be dense?

Comment: @GerryMyerson terminology for represenation of polynomial. whether you given the coefficients in a fixed order (dense) or give coefficient and the monomial term the coefficient occurs (sparse). Sparse polynomials can have very large degrees.